# I use LWJGL and the JOML library, but when I multiply matrices it doesn't work

Tags: java, macos, 3d, lwjgl, joml

I start learning LWJGL very recently and I am trying to get a simple shader to work. I followed an "old" tutorial but when I run the code no shapes appear (the window open but it is just black). Here is my .vs file for my shader :

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 transformWorld;
uniform mat4 transformObject;
uniform mat4 cameraProjection;

void main() {
    gl_Position = cameraProjection * transformWorld * transformObject * vec4(position, 1);
}
```

I don't know what to send to show the problem but here is my main file

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Window window = new Window();
        window.createWindow(700, 700, "window");
        window.init();
        
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
        mesh.create(new float[] {
                -1, -1 ,0,
                0, 1  ,0,
                1, -1 ,0
        });
        
        Shader shader = new Shader();
        shader.create("basic");
        
        Camera camera = new Camera();
        Transform transform = new Transform();
        
        camera.setPersepective((float)Math.toRadians(70), 640.0f / 480.0f, 0.01f, 1000.0f);
        camera.setPosition(new Vector3f(0, 1, 3));
        camera.setRotation(new Quaternionf(new AxisAngle4f((float)Math.toRadians(-30), new Vector3f(1, 0, 0))));
        
        boolean isRunning = true;
        float x = 0;
        
        while(isRunning) {
            isRunning = !window.shouldColse();
            
            x += 0.01f;
            transform.setPosition(new Vector3f((float)Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x)), 0, 0));
            transform.getRotation().rotateAxis((float)Math.toRadians(1), 0, 1, 0);
            
            glfwPollEvents();
            
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            
            shader.useShader();
            shader.setCamera(camera);
            shader.setTranform(transform);
            mesh.draw();
            
            window.swapBuffers();
        }
        shader.destroy();
        mesh.destroy();
        window.destroy();
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the shader function:

```
public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
    if (uniMatProjection != -1) {
        float matrix[] = new float[16];
        camera.getProjection().get(matrix);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniMatProjection, false, matrix);
    }
    if (uniMatTransformWorld != -1) {
        float matrix[] = new float[16];
        camera.getTransformation().get(matrix);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniMatTransformWorld, false, matrix);
    }
}
    
public void setTranform(Transform transform) {
    if (uniMatTransformObject != -1) {
        float matrix[] = new float[16];
        transform.getTransformation().get(matrix);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uniMatTransformObject, false, matrix);
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the camera:

```
public class Camera {
    private Vector3f position;
    private Quaternionf rotation;
    private Matrix4f projection;
    
    public Camera() {
        this.position = new Vector3f();
        this.rotation = new Quaternionf();
        this.projection = new Matrix4f();
    }
    
    public Matrix4f getTransformation() {
        Matrix4f returnValue = new Matrix4f();
        
        returnValue.rotate(rotation.conjugate(new Quaternionf()));
        returnValue.translate(position.mul(-1, new Vector3f()));
        
        return returnValue;
    }
    
    public void setOrthographics(float left, float right, float top, float bottom) {
        projection.setOrtho2D(left, right, bottom, top);
    }
    
    public void setPersepective(float fov, float aspectRatio, float zNear, float zFar) {
        projection.setPerspective(fov, aspectRatio, zNear, zFar);
    }

    public Vector3f getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Vector3f position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public Quaternionf getRotation() {
        return rotation;
    }

    public void setRotation(Quaternionf rotation) {
        this.rotation = rotation;
    }

    public Matrix4f getProjection() {
        return projection;
    }
}
```

Here the code for the transform:

```
public class Transform {
    private Vector3f position;
    private Quaternionf rotation;
    private Vector3f scale;
    
    public Transform() {
        position = new Vector3f();
        rotation = new Quaternionf();
        scale = new Vector3f(1); 
    }
    
    public Matrix4f getTransformation() {
        Matrix4f returnValue = new Matrix4f();
        
        returnValue.translate(position);
        returnValue.rotate(rotation);
        returnValue.scale(scale);
        
        return returnValue;
    }

    public Vector3f getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Vector3f position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public Quaternionf getRotation() {
        return rotation;
    }

    public void setRotation(Quaternionf rotation) {
        this.rotation = rotation;
    }

    public Vector3f getScale() {
        return scale;
    }

    public void setScale(Vector3f scale) {
        this.scale = scale;
    }
}
```

and the Mesh class

```
public class Mesh {

    private int vertexArrayObject;
    private int vertexBufferObject;
    
    private int vertexCount;
    
    public Mesh() {
    }
    
    public boolean create(float vertices[]) {
        vertexArrayObject = glGenVertexArrays();
        glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);
        
        vertexBufferObject = glGenBuffers();
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferObject);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        
        vertexCount = vertices.length / 3;
        
        return true;
    }
    
    public void destroy() {
        glDeleteBuffers(vertexBufferObject);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(vertexArrayObject);
    }
    
    public void draw() {
        glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayObject);
        
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, vertexCount);
        
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
}
```

And I work with macOS. I hope I am clear and someone could help me.

Comment: You should send us some more code because the problem could be in other classes.

Comment: Anyway, I suggest you to try for first, with some basic things:
1) in the while loop, remove the transform's rotation and set a simple position like `new Vector3f(0, 0, 0)`
2) same thing for the camera
3) try to scale up the object you're trying to render. Maybe it's just too small or it's scale is set to 0! I can't explain you how to change the `Mesh` scale because you didn't sent us it's code but you can try.
(Also, sorry for my bad english LOL)

Comment: You can also try to add a simple camera motion (or simply try to start your program with the camera position changed manually) and once in the window, move around because the mesh may not be in the position you think it is

Comment: thank you, I will try it and I put more code in the question

Comment: Another IMPORTANT thing you can try is to set `camera.setPersepective()` last two values to `... , 0.0f, 10000.0f)`. If you don't change this, your object may be too close or too far to the camera, so it won't be rendered

Comment: I try all of this and it don't work, the object is rendered only if the .vs file is like that:
`#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 transformWorld;
uniform mat4 transformObject;
uniform mat4 cameraProjection;

void main() {
 gl_Position = cameraProjection * vec4(position, 1);
}`
But if I do that, there are no transformation

Comment: I found the problem, in the shader class, I was setting value too early. Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The problem was that in the shader class, I was setting values too early, and the matrices multiplication can't work because of that. We just need to put

```
uniMatProjection = glGetUniformLocation(program, "cameraProjection");
        uniMatTransformWorld = glGetUniformLocation(program, "transformWorld");
        uniMatTransformObject = glGetUniformLocation(program, "transformObject");
```

at the end of setCamera and setTransform in the Shader class

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).